# Jenkins Build Pipeline plugin with empty ${PIPELINE_VERSION}

Tags: maven, jenkins, build-pipeline-plugin

I'm using Build Pipeline plugin in Jenkins.

I've set a job and configured it to create the delivery pipeline version. The result will be something like: 3.0.0_r119723_b5

[image]

I can see the jobs are displayed with the correct build titles (the pipeline version).

After that, I need to pass this variable to Maven, but the ${PIPELINE_VERSION} always arrives empty.

```
clean install -Dapplication.version=${PIPELINE_VERSION}
```

I've already tried to remove the "{" and "}" but it didn't work. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Apparentely this is a bug in Maven Project plugin. I've updated both Maven Project and Delivery Pipeline plugins and now the ${PIPELINE_VERSION} works.